# Integration over a spherical surface

Tags: integration

Suppose that we have let's say a function of "something" that is everywhere on the spherical surface zero except at one point it is finite. Why is the integral of such a function over the surface is zero?

Comment: You mean you have a (discontinuous) function $f:S^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z)=0$ except for one value of $z$?

Comment: I don't know about the S^2 --> R notation but the function is everywhere zero on the shpere except at one point. @rogerl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set where the integrand is not zero is a zero set. Therefore the integral vanishes.

Comment: May you please elaborate? I don't know a lot about sets. I probably should have posted this is the Physics section?

Comment: Just note that in the definition of the Riemann-sum, changing the integrand (the function you try to integrate) on just one point does not change anything (in the limit): $\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i-1})$

Comment: Aha but here we are talking not on just one point, we are intergating over the whole sphere. Sorry if I am not following you quickly. Does this have a proof or something I can look at? @sanjab

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)$ is identically zero in $[a,b]$ expect at some point $c$ in between then the definite integral from $a$ to $b$ would vanish. Your question is analogous to this example. The example which you said is taking place in higher dimensions so we are not able to visualise it. Hope you get my point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing (and accepted) answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I feel like I should point out that the OP was confused by the phrasing of the accepted answer. It's possible that one dimensional integrals are more familiar to the OP, and thus that this answer will be more helpful in providing insight.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations we use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).